# Atom Editor-view whitespace character

Tags: atom-editor

I am a newbie in python and I like Atom Editor, you know the indentation precision and spaces control is really important.

How can Atom-editor show non printable characters (I'm interested in SPACEs and TABs)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To show white space chars in Atom open up the config file ( file --> config). 
Then under the invisibles:{} line enter this line:

```
showInvisibles: true
```

Then save the file. The white spaces will now be visible such as spaces; tabs & EOL

[image]

Comment: For Mac OSX, it was under the Atom menu.

Answer (score 53):

There is a `Show Invisibles` checkbox in the Editor Settings.

You can customize how these characters look too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + p`  -> `toggle invisibles` on Atom 1.23

Answer (score 2):

Use find (Ctrl+F), set regex, search for [^[:print:][:space:]]

Comment: OP was looking for a persistent solution from configuration, not how to search for these characters.